# Access 2007 Error 3151 from DAO.OpenRecordSet. How to fix?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2007, dao

Well this is fascinating. I am using `MS-Access 2007` to make a from that will allow users to enter data from lab results.

The from utilizes a `VBA` code call:

`DAO.OpenRecordset("{Sql query}" , DB_OPEN_DYNASET, dbSeeChanges)`

This call normally works just fine, but I've noticed that when this form is closed and then re-opened, a `3151 ODBC` error is generated.

We are using linked tables through `Access 2007` for this form, our `SQL-Server 2012` version is as follows.

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                    11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                                             3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 8.0.7601.17514
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.237
Operating System                                            6.1.7601
```

The `DAO.OpenRecordset` call is utilized in multiple events. Here is the list.

`On_Current , _AfterUpdate , Form_Unload`

I have found several reported instances of similar errors on `Access 2007` with linked tables to `SQL-Server`, but none seem to have workable solutions for this issue.

As best I can tell, the `3151` doesn't appear to be affecting the form or data in any negative way. I am able to open the form and everything is where it should be as best I can tell. There are about 20 thousand records on this table, so I may be missing something.

Does anyone have any ideas?

9/14 In response to comments I am adding some additional code.

Here is the call on Form_Unload. It contains the failing line.

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
Dim ImportID
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Set ImportID = Me.ImportID

#This is the failing line below. 
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [dbo_t_inspect].* FROM [dbo_t_inspect] WHERE [dbo_t_inspect].ImportID= " & ImportID & ";", DB_OPEN_DYNASET, dbSeeChanges)
```

Here is the call from On_Current. This On_Current call is actually made by a sub-form on the main form.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strImportID As String
If IsNull(Me.ImportID) Then
    [Forms]![Inspection Receiving]![LabComplete].Visible = False
    [Forms]![Inspection Receiving]![LabPending].Visible = True
Else
strImportID = Me.ImportID

Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [dbo_t_health].*, [dbo_t_health].ImportID FROM [dbo_t_health] WHERE ((([dbo_t_health].ImportID)=" & Me.ImportID & "));", DB_OPEN_DYNASET, dbSeeChanges)
```

I am not sure where `DAO` is defined in this solution. I cannot find it's declaration in my folder titled `Microsoft Office Access Class Objects` I am open to suggestions on where that might be located.

The precise error message is as follows

> Failed to connect to {ODBC Connection Name} Error 3151.

I can then select the debug option and the debugger will take me to the line that tried and failed to connect the the ODBC Connection I am using.

The Error is highly reproducible. All I have to do is enable `VBA` Macros on the Security Alert and then open the form in question. I close out the form after it loads. Once I attempt to reopen the form, I get the error described above. The Form opens anyway after I click `Ok` on the error.

Comment: Isn't there a message with the error number? -- Why do you open a recordset in all these events? Especially in Form_Current this is problematic.

Comment: It's `dbOpenDynaset` not `DB_OPEN_DYNASET`, unless you've defined that yourself

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Actually `DB_OPEN_DYNASET` is valid and still included for backwards compatibility in Microsoft Access.  All of the built-in constants were named in that fashion back in Access 1.x and 2.x.  In Access 97 Microsoft introduced the current namings that we are all familiar with.  Seeing that in his question, I was going to ask how long this particular solution has been around, or if they hired a guy from the 1990's to write it ;-)

Comment: @JerichoJohnson Thanks, learning something new every day.

Comment: @Edward Please post a sample of the actual code that is failing, along with the declaration of your variables, in particular the `DAO` variable because `DAO` is a reserved word (namespace) and there isn't a `DAO.OpenRecordSet` method.  `OpenRecordSet` is a method of a `DAO.RecordSet` object.  Also, when you add the actual code, please indicate what line of code is getting the error, and include the full error number and message so that we can help you.

Comment: Hello, all this solution was built circa 2008 on `MS-Access 2007`. I have not asked my manager who originally built this system, I know that it wasn't him since he doesn't know enough `VBA` to make something like what I am currently working on. Based on some other parts of the implementation I've seen so far, I would guess that the person/team that built this for my company was definitely using outdated practices.I will post the specific line that is failing, but it is very similar to what is already in the question. What is the issue with using On_Current?

Comment: Is `DAO` not a standard method baked into `MS-Access`? This msdn article lead me to believe that it was https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx.

Comment: `DAO` is the namespace.  It doesn't directly have an `OpenRecordSet` method. If you look at the article you linked, it is `Database.OpenRecordSet` and says `(DAO)` in parenthesis afterwards to indicate the topic is DAO as opposed to ADO. You could have `DAO.Database.OpenRecordSet` but not what you originally posted.  Your update makes more sense.

Comment: You still haven't provided the exact text of the error message. It appears to be `ODBC - Connection to 'YourServer' failed`, which would be rather clear. Does this happen on all machines running your DB? Or just some? Is it reproducible every time? Or just random?

Comment: I'm not sure about any other machines. The error is highly reproducible. See my edits. And it doesn't occur randomly, but rather when I re-open the form after closing it.

Comment: I'm suspecting `Set ImportID = Me.ImportID`. Remove the set keyword, dim ImportId  as long? and use importID = nz(me.importid.value,0)